# Apparmor denies several processes since a kernel change

Tags: apparmor, dhclient

I happened to encounter a very weird problem. I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 in development mode since around April, and ever since I have been trying to stay on the latest kernel RC to avoid nasty problems with suspend and GPU that I've had on my Dell Precision.

Since I have installed 4.14-rc2, I suddenly lost WiFi connectivity. After running bisect I narrowed the problem down to [a changeset in the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=651e28c5537abb39076d3949fb7618536f1d242e) that has updated Apparmor.

Looking at `journalctl -xe` output I noticed that a lot of errors like that appeared:

`Oct 27 14:45:48 precision audit[6088]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/sbin/dhclient" pid=6088 comm="dhclient" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"`

Errors like this happened also for procceses `mysqld`, `avahi-daemon` and `cups-browsed`. I have disabled the profiles for these processes with the following command:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient /etc/apparmor.d/disable
$ sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient
```

And boom, I have WiFi back. But is this the right way to handle this situation? Should I modify the profiles instead, or submit a bug to Launchpad about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, major changes to kernel security (i.e. apparmor) missed kernel 4.14-rc1 due to some issues but were included in kernel 4.14-rc2. And yes, there is a non-backwards compatible change.

Myself, I either compile the kernel with apparmor disabled, or more simply just boot with it disabled. i.e. in `/etc/default/grub":

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300 apparmor=0"
```

The related launchpad bug report (even though the description is a little wrong) is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/1721278). It does have some work arounds.

Note that this question and answer might end up being put on hold, because the release candidate kernels are actually not supported here.

**EDIT:** late breaking entry from the bug report:

> The kernel patch causing the issue has been reverted. So 4.14-rc7
>   should work as pre 4.14-rc2